# PL SQL output in hackerrank

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
I NUMBER;
J NUMBER;
BEGIN
FOR I IN REVERSE 1..20
LOOP
    FOR J IN 1..I
    LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('* ') ; -- printing *
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE; -- for new line
END LOOP;
END;
```

'

Can anyone tell me why this code is not showing any output in the Hackerank question (Draw The Triangle) even after selecting Oracle?

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/draw-the-triangle-1/problem

Comment: Looks like it only accepts SQL. It mentions 'stdout', which PL/SQL doesn't have.

Comment: I tried `select rpad('*',21 - rownum,'*') from xmltable('1 to 20');` which meets the stated requirement as far as I can tell, but it says it's the wrong answer. I'm bored with Hackerrank now.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - you forgot the spaces *8-) It seems happy with `select rpad('*',2*(21 - rownum),' *') from xmltable('1 to 20');`. But yes, also bored with it already...

Comment: @AlexPoole Ah, thanks. It also appears to need a final slash character as you spotted in your answer. Who knew.

Comment: @Tanishka Now that Alex as cracked how to run PL/SQL on Hackerrank, you could improve the answer by removing the whole `DECLARE` section, because your loops implicitly declare `i` and `j` so the ones at the top aren't used. Then you could replace the inner loop with `dbms_output.put_line(rpad('* ', i * 2, '* '));` And you don't have to code in uppercase :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That site doesn't seem to ever show your the output from your submission, unhelpfully, but does with just 'run code'. Surprisingly it does seem to understand PL/SQL; and even more surprisingly it handles the `set serveroutput on`, which is a SQL\Plus/SQL Developer client command.

But you need to add a terminating `/` after your code, on a line on its own - again, just like SQL*Plus (though SQL Developer is sometimes doesn't complain):

```
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Your code <strike>doesn't produce the expected output because it</strike> has a trailing space on each line. Instead of:

```
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('* ') ; -- printing *
```

skip the space on the last iteration:

```
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('*') ; -- printing *
    IF J < I THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(' ');
    END IF;
```

So this produces the expected output, and passes the test:

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
I NUMBER; -- redundant
J NUMBER; -- redundant
BEGIN
FOR I IN REVERSE 1..20
LOOP
    FOR J IN 1..I
    LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('*') ; -- printing *
    IF J < I THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(' ');
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE; -- for new line
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[image: Screenshot from HackerRank]

However, your original code also passes the test, despite the trailing spaces, if you just add the terminating `/`:

[image]

Comment: It still give output as: no response on stdout

Comment: I've just followed your original link, selected Oracle, pasted the code from my answer, and clicked 'Run code'. It shows the output and says 'Congratulations'.

Comment: @TanishkaVashisht - presumably you were still missing the `/`, which I added so automatically I hadn't thought to explicitly refer to it. Your original code passes with that too, though it possibly shouldn't. As William has said, this isn't an efficient or elegant solution...

Comment: yeah it's working now after adding /. But what's the use of this.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SQL-Plus-basics.html#GUID-1C95D0FD-41A2-487A-A1F0-10509B8FC62C