# PLSQL ~ no response on stdout ~ in Hackerrank

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to run the following code in hackerrank but while running the query I am getting output as ~ no response on stdout ~

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
l_publisherid   publisher.publisherid%type;
begin
insert into publisher (publishername) values ('ttk publisher')
returning publisherid into l_publisherid;

update book b set
b.publisherid = l_publisherid
where b.publisherid is null;

for cur_r in 
(select b.bookid, 
 substr(b.title, 1, 10) title, 
 p.publishername publisher, 
 a.firstname ||' '|| a.lastname author
 from book b join publisher p on p.publisherid = b.publisherid
 join author a on a.authorid = b.author_id
 where p.publisherid = l_publisherid)
loop
   dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.bookid||'.............'||cur_r.title     
   ||'.............'||cur_r.publisher ||'.............'||cur_r.author);
END LOOP;
END;
/
exit;
```

Comment: HackerRank [does understand PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66722178/266304), so maybe the `exit;` is confusing it? Or how you're running it, perhaps. If that doesn't work then maybe link to the challenge so we can see it in context.

Comment: I tried running the code without exit statement but still the same error and the hackerrank question link I have is specific to my organization so I cant share it here

Comment: Maybe you just don't have any matching data then; if there are no books without publishers to update, the cursor loop won't find any data and it won't ever hit a `dbms_output` call. Maybe add some debugging - check you actually get a value back on `l_publisherid` for example (this assumes that ID is an identity column or has a trigger to set the ID), and not null; and print how many books are updated. (`a.authorid = b.author_id` looks odd because of the inconsistent naming; but if that was wrong you should see the error in the stdout pane.)

Comment: @NinadMuranjan Can you provide the link to the problem?